# Change login screen

Tags: windows, windows-vista, software-rec, login

How do I change the login screen in Windows Vista to show the clock and world clock?

Comment: So you want to show the clock on the login screen?

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit? I only slightly improved the capitalization, I didn't to anything bad to it..

Comment: @alex - i didn't know about because i also edited that time

Comment: @joe Ok, now I feel a bit better. I thought you were mad because I edited your question :)

Comment: @alex - Never like that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Its not possible :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following tutorial http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-your-windows-vista-logon-screen/

Comment: Thanks :-) . but it doesn't have information about adding the clock in the login screen

Comment: That's probably as good as you can get. I don't think you can do more than change the background image.

Comment: Do there exist any "dynamic" backgrounds?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to see a clock when you have your account locked and you're at the login screen?

Since in that case I think the only solution is to install a clock screensaver and make it *On resume, display logon screen*

That way you're computer will show whichever clock screensaver you can find and will return you to the login screen if you have to logon again.

[image]

Note: I understand this isn't what you're asking for. But AFAIK you can only change the background image of your logon screen and I don't think there exist any dynamic wallpapers that would allow you to have a clock on it...

Comment: thanks for your effort . but its not a good solution